# Getting started with react css modules

Tags: reactjs, react-css-modules

I am setting up [react-css-modules](https://github.com/gajus/react-css-modules#decorator).  Following the readme I have added two files:

#### cssModulesDemoPage.js

```
import React from 'react';
import CSSModules from 'react-css-modules';
import styles from './cssModulesDemoPage-style.css';

//I am not familiar with decorators.  I dont know 
//That I used this properly
@CSSModules(styles)   
export default class extends React.Component {
    render () {
        return <div styleName='table'>
            <div styleName='row'>
                <div styleName='cell'>A0</div>
                <div styleName='cell'>B0</div>
            </div>
        </div>;
    }
}
```

#### cssModulesDemoPage-style.css

```
.table {

}

.row {

}

.cell {
  color: red;
}
```

I followed the [setup instructions for webpack](https://github.com/gajus/react-css-modules#webpack) installing:

- style-loader
- css-loader
- added loader to webpack.config.dev.js

When I navigate to this page I get a cryptic error:

> Uncaught TypeError: type.toUpperCase is not a function

I tried following the [webpack demo](https://css-modules.github.io/webpack-demo/).  The syntax is different so its not very useful to me.

Comment: Maybe it's trying to call `toUpperCase` on your anonymous class. try giving it a name `export default class MyClass ..`

Comment: @azium - Added class name.  Same error

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the return value with parentheses, like you did with the `createClass` version?

Comment: @user1164937 - Ah I didn't notice that error.  I bet that was the source of the issue.